# how to maintain a book with git examples?

Tags: git

I am writing a <s>book</s> manual where I use examples that use git branches and stuff. Right now, I have a repo for the book and a separate repo for the examples (examples are not just files... it's branches where I change files and run git operations on them)... but the examples change over time as I add/edit/remove stuff from the book. I was thinking that it would be great if I could keep the examples *state* as part of the information for a revision on the book repo. Like, setting up a book repo, inside there's an *examples* dir/repo and I will add the examples/.git directory to the parent book repo? I know that won't fly. But what would be the options?

I was thinking that I might set up a directory with all the different patch files (as produced with format-patch, say) that make up the examples, have a script that could rebuild the whole examples directory on the fly (all example branches and their history).... that might work... but are there simpler approaches?

Just in case, having the examples be other branches of the book repo does not make sense because those branches will change over time and I want to be able to do something like `go back to how the book was 2 months ago` and I want to see the examples as they were *back then*. Having them be separate branches on the book repo would not pull it off.

### Update

One way I think I can do it is by creating a very big revision (with `git commit-tree`) that has all of the separate branches as parents..... first parent would be the book itself and the tree could be the book project's revision tree. Not the most elegant way to do it, but it certainly holds the water.

Comment: how about using git submodules for examples ?
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules you can update submodule whenever required and it works similar to a git repo without explicitly having aexamples/.git dir

Comment: I think submodules do not tie the revision of the parent repo to the submodule when you create a revision. Is that correct? If that is the case, then it won't hold water.

Comment: Even more, if submodules did tie a revision of the submodule to the parent revision, that would still not be good enough because I need to point to _all_ branches of the submodule (somehow) when I ceate a revision on the book repo. In other words, it's not just the revision that is checked out on the submodule that matters.

Comment: yes, submodules are independent and do not have any tie with parent repo apart from its checked-out commit in parent repo. 
how about this: contrary to your last suggestion, start with empty repo, create two branches for book and examples (only examples), keep adding content in both till you can merge examples in book, then tag merge commit with month/date and continue same process. just a thought right now :)

Comment: @kalimba but examples are not just plain files. The examples are branches themselves and I would need to save the history of _all the branches in the examples directory_ when I create a book revision.

Comment: Submodules (or separate repositories) + `post-checkout` hook in the superproject (the book) + a kind of a database for the hook that remembers SHA1 IDs for all branches in all submodules.

Comment: having each one of the examples as a separate submodule instead of having them al together in a single repo?

Comment: No, I meant submodules don't buy you much, superproject can only store one reference into submodule and you need many ones (all branches of a submodule). So if submodules isn't a solution you can avoid them at all and use separate repositories.